# Is it better to use exoplayer from a background thread or from the main ui thread?

Tags: exoplayer

To avoid any jerk in the application, is it better to use exoplayer from a background thread or using it from the main ui thread is OK ?

**NOTE:** When i create an simpleExoPlayer in the main ui thread doing :

```
// 1. Create a default TrackSelector
Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
TrackSelector trackSelector =
    new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

// 2. Create the player
SimpleExoPlayer player =
    ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
```

then it's took **90 ms** !! it's too much slow and i will have several frame drop resulting in jerk in my animation. Also doing

```
// Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
    Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
    .createMediaSource(mp4VideoUri);
// Prepare the player with the source.
player.prepare(videoSource);
```

took around **20ms** ! it's also slow to much slow and i will have another frame drop

Comment: The first snippet can be done only once for an activtiy. Create the player instance and reuse it later. You can prepare the same instance as often you want.

Comment: Then in the second snippet you should avoid creating the DataSource.Factory and the DefaultBandWidthMeter multiple times. Do this once and reuse these objects when you create a new MediaSource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The internals of ExoPlayer take care of threading - so it is safe to call most of the APIs on the main (application) thread.

From the [documentation](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html):

> It is recommended that ExoPlayer instances are created and accessed from a single application thread. The application's main thread is ideal. Accessing an instance from multiple threads is discouraged, however if an application does wish to do this then it may do so provided that it ensures accesses are synchronized.

[image: ExoPlayer Threading Model Diagram]

Comment: Thanks @KyleVenn, I did like this but i have now terrible time taken, it's took around 100 ms to create the Exoplayer :( yes prepare is still fast, but everything else is terribly slow :( I just updated the question with those numbers. maybe i do something wrong ?

Comment: You might want to look through the issue tracker perhaps? And if you don't find an answer in there, you could post a new issue with your findings. Your code looks correct to me. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2575

Answer (score 1):

Besides Kyle's explanation it can be added that with the exception of the `release()` call, all calls are non-blocking in a sense that a message is sent to the thread the player is running in.

`release()` will block until resources are released. Calling `release()` is only needed if you completely destroy the player instance. If you want to reuse the player instance with eg. another media source calling `stop()` is sufficient.

In case `stop` has already been called then all `release()` will actually do is block on any still-pending `stop` operation, and finally kill the playback thread.

Comment: Thanks marc but seam that it's took around 100 ms to create the Exoplayer and i don't even study yet the release :( So it's too much slow :( I just updated the question with those numbers. maybe i do something wrong ?

Comment: Where does the requirements come from to create the player so quickly? Are you in a recyclerview? I'd create the instance of ExoPlayer once onStart/onResume of the activity/fragment and reuse the same player instance again and again when the users scrolls.

Comment: thanks marc, but in the doc they say it's better to throw the player and recreate a new one when we need to play a different video :(

Comment: Can you please point me to that doc where this is mentioned? I don't think that is true and the documentation needs to be fixed if so.

Comment: exemple in player.java: MediaSource instances are not designed to be re-used. If you want to prepare a player more than once with the same piece of media, use a new instance each time.

Comment: Yes, this is true. But it means the instance of the MediaSource not the player instance. You can definitely call prepare() on the same player multiple times. You need to recreate the MediaSource only which are not designed to be re-used.

Comment: yes but as creating the mediasource cost me 20ms i can't do it in the main thread else i will have a frame drop :(